# How to prove $\mathbb Q(i)=\mathbb Q(\frac{2i+1}{i-1})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the elements in these two groups, but how to prove that $\mathbb Q(i)=\mathbb Q(\frac{2i+1}{i-1})$ ?

Can the second thing be replaced by other complex numbers?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the notation $\Bbb Q(i)$ when speaking about groups. What does it mean?

Comment: What does your notation mean? Are you looking at field extensions of the rationals?  If so, then just note that $\frac {2i+1}{i-1}=\frac {1-3i}2$ so $i$ is contained in the field on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{2i+1}{i-1} = \frac12 - \frac32 i$.

Hence $$\frac{2i+1}{i-1} = \underbrace{\frac12}_{\in\mathbb{Q}} - \underbrace{\frac32 i}_{\in\mathbb{Q}(i)} \in \mathbb{Q}(i)$$
so $\mathbb{Q}\left(\frac{2i+1}{i-1}\right) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Conversely, we have $$i = \underbrace{\frac13}_{\in\mathbb{Q}} - \underbrace{\frac23\frac{2i+1}{i-1}}_{\in\mathbb{Q}\left(\frac{2i+1}{i-1}\right)} \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\frac{2i+1}{i-1}\right)$$
so $\mathbb{Q}(i) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}\left(\frac{2i+1}{i-1}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathbb{Q}(\frac{2i+1}{i-1})=\mathbb{Q}(2+\frac{3}{i-1})=\mathbb{Q}(\frac{i+2}{-2})=\mathbb{Q}(-\frac{i}{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\frac i 2)$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suppose your first question is already answered. Now take a complex number $x+iy, x,y \neq 0$ (if $x=0, y\neq 0$ it's trivial and if $y =0$ it's impossible) and suppose $\Bbb Q(i) = \Bbb Q(x+iy)$. So $(a+bx) + i\cdot by = i$ for some choice of $a, b$. Then $b = -a/x$ and then $-ay/x = 1$ for some choice of $a$. Then $a = -x/y \in \Bbb Q$ is our choice and with $\Bbb Q(i) \supseteq Q(x+iy)$ trivially, we do also get by closure of sum that $\Bbb Q(x+iy) \supseteq Q(i)$ so they're equal.

So this occurs iff there's a way to write $y = 1/b$ and $x = a/b$, i.e., $(x,y) \in \Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q_*$.

Comment: And now note that $\frac{2i+1}{i-1} = \frac{-2 - 2i + i - 1}{2} = -3/2 + 1/2\cdot i$. So $(-3/2, 1/2)$ is our choice and it works perfectly.